# Building production environment for Java Server Faces application on server

Tags: java, jsf

I am about to start working on a JSF application and I am trying to decide on how to set up my production environment.

I enjoy working off my VPS for production instead of my local host. Is there a way to launch a JSF app to my server and then build on it from there? Or is that not going to work because I have to have a compiler to compile the java each time I update?

If that is the case would it make sense to just install a compiler to the server?

This is my first JSF and real java application so if there is some good info on this please lead me there. 
I have someone working with me and I was assuming if we both work of the server it would be easiest.

How would this work in a professional environment, or in other words how would a team working for a company set their environment up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How it generally works is that each team member has a local installation, and deployments up the chain to servers are handled by the systems admin guys on requests, them being provided with an installation package containing the compiled application (a WAR or EAR file), any other files needed, and quite likely a script with database changes, an installation manual, and things like that.

You should never develop directly on a production server. Only deploy stuff there once it's complete, tested, and verified to be in working order, and secured against attacks.